# Wordpress Video placeholder is black on Safari

Tags: wordpress, safari

Hi I'm Having an issue with safari browser the video actually plays when I click play but the problem is its place holder on chrome, Firefox the 1st part of the video is its placeholder but not in safari Please see Image [image]

but on firefox or chrome it displays correctly 
[image]

I'm not sure whats wrong, but can this be solved?
this happens only in safari browser btw

here is the code I used although I dont know if its relevant but since someone ask me to show my code.

```
              <div class="col-lg-12">  
                <?php query_posts('page_id=999'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>                    
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 
          </div>
```

Comment: Don't be shy to show your code :P

Comment: @sdcr Done although I still dont know how it would be relevant because its a post page so basically I queried it like how you would query a page. but If you could find a way through the code that calls the content then by all do means please teach me :)

Comment: The PHP code isn't explain any about the video issue, by the way you'd better add `wp_reset_query();`after `endif;` can you post the HTML?